# The Concept of Parallel Resistors

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance

**If the equivalent resistance of resistors in parallel is lower than all resistors, does this mean each resistor is resisting less than its maximum (what is written on its label)?**

I am trying to understand why the sum of reciprocal resistances gives/tells you how much resistance is occurring in a parallel circuit. I am trying to understand this in concepts - mainly. I only want to use Ohm's law when necessary.

I can take Ohm's law as fact, since one fact of reality is that as I increase a circuit's' current I decrease the resistance of a resistor. However, I want to understand this fact conceptually. Since, Ohm's law is built on first principles of the Laws of conservation of energy and mass I want to be able to describe resistance with these conceptual principles. I see how voltage is related to the conservation of energy. I also see how current is related to conservation of mass. I don't see how resistance is related to these founding concepts.

I am also aiming to visualize what is happening. For instance if current is increasing I imagine there are more electrons passing the resistor at a given time, like fast moving cars passing through a traffic light. But, why wouldn't a resistor slow the electrons down? Why are the cars ignoring the yellow/red light?

Comment: “_Ohm's law as fact, since one fact of reality is that as I increase a circuit's' current I decrease the resistance of a resistor_” the resistance in a circuit is a constant. That’s the point of Ohms’ law $$\frac{V}{I}=R$$ “_also see how current is related to conservation of mass._” no. It’s related to conservation of charge.

Comment: I don't see how this is a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a pack of identical resistors.

One of these resistors will allow a given current for a given voltage (Ohm's Law).

You can appreciate how multiple resistors in parallel means multiple paths for current to flow. Which means more current flow for a given voltage.

This is the equivalent to lowering the resistance when using a single resistor.

Therefore you can appreciate for a given set of parallel resistors, there is also an equivalent single resistance value which allows the same current for a given voltage (Ohm's Law).

Rather than traffic lights, it may help to think of a tank of water with thin pipes.

You can appreciate how one thicker pipe could permit the same water flow as multiple thinner pipes?

Comment: You say "You can appreciate how multiple resistors in parallel means multiple paths for current to flow. Which means more current flow for a given voltage." But current doesn't increase just by adding more resistors? When current has multiple flow paths, it is only a fraction of the current that passes through a given resistor in parallel, according to Kirchoff's junction law.

Comment: > "it is only a fraction of the current that passes through a given resistor in parallel"

That is the point, recall for equivalent resistance you account for the sum of multiple parallel current paths when finding the equivalent resistance. 

The total current increases because there are multiple paths (through the multiple resistors). If you sum the current through these multiple resistor paths, there is of course a single resistance value which allows the same current to flow for a given voltage (via Ohm's Law).

Comment: To put another way, a resistor will just limit the current for a given voltage. If voltage is constant, the current through a single resistor does not change, no matter how many you place in parallel with eachother. But of course the TOTAL current through ALL resistors increases (because there are more resistors for current to flow through). It is the total current which interests us in this case. The idea being you can now replace a 'complicated' many-parallel-resistor circuit with a single resistor (which passes the same total current), which is generally much easier to analyse etc.

Comment: But of course the TOTAL current through ALL resistors increases (because there are more resistors for current to flow through). I still don't think this is what is happening. I think what happens is that there is an initial current that is divided amongst parallel resistors, as it enters each one, and then those fractional currents meet up (summing to the initial current) before passing through the battery.    Maybe if you provided a picture I could see what your are saying.

Comment: @Haley, please see my answer across 2 comments below. It's important to pay attention to the wording: Note I said "for a given voltage". I chose 'given voltage' as a starting point since, recall if $V=0$ then $I=0$ regardless of whatever resistance you have. But it is also ok to view it from your example of an initial current divided through the resistors, but we must be careful not to neglect voltage and we must be mindful of the V, I & R relationships governed by Ohm's Law. Let us use your example, but also note the voltages:  (comment 1/2)

Comment: Consider a current of $1A$ flowing through a single $R=1\Omega$ resistor, from Ohm's Law $V=1$. Now consider $1A$ flowing through two parallel $1\Omega$ resistors, as you said the current through each resistor is divided, so $0.5A$ through each resistor. According to Ohm's Law the voltage drop on each resistor is $V=0.5$. It is not that anything about the resistor has changed, it is the voltage which has changed! Is there a resistance which will allow $1A$ to pass if we apply a voltage of $0.5V$? Yes $0.5\Omega$ which is the equivalent resistance of two $1\Omega$ resistors in parallel. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

It’s **exactly** like putting two hoses between two tanks, or two hoses between a pump and wherever you are sending the water. The two hoses in parallel would resist flow less. But each still behaves as described on the label. (Same comparison works for putting them in series too)

---

In fluid dynamics, pressure difference.. drives flow. More pressure difference, more flow.

In circuits, voltage.. drives current. More voltage, more current.

---

In fluid dynamics, pipes resist flow. More restrictive pipes resist flow more. For the same pressure difference, more restrictive pipe means less flow.

In circuits, resistors resist current. Higher resistance resists current more. For the same voltage, more resistant resistor means less current.

---

Putting two pipes in series makes less flow (if same pressure difference). Twice as restrictive.

Putting two resistors in series makes less current (if same voltage difference). Twice as much resistance.

---

Putting them in parallel give two pathways.

Comment: "It’s exactly like putting two hoses between two tanks, or two hoses between a pump and wherever you are sending the water. The two hoses in parallel would resist flow less. But each still behaves as described on the label." But, if each hose is resisting less, then it isn't resisting water flow in the exact way/amount their labels say.

Comment: @Haley The labels tell how much they restrict, per unit of flow. So if put in parallel then flow per hose goes down and restriction goes down, but still match the label.  Resistance (on the label) tells how much voltage drop per unit current. Putting in parallel reduces current in each resistor and hence reduces total voltage drop, but each resistor still resisting as per label